# Tetris full row only half-removed

Tags: java, algorithm, processing

I'm trying to create a Tetris game with Processing 3.

My problem is that the highest full row gets only half deleted.
Here are a couple of screenshots to illustrate what happens before the last move:

[image: Before the last move]

And after the last move:

[image]

Here's the code that handles the deletion of the lines:

```
void remove_full_line() {
  for(int h = 900; h > 0; h-=50) {
    if (line_sum(h) == 12) { // 12 column-canvas
      for (int i = 0; i < fallen_tetros.size(); i++) {
        if (fallen_tetros.get(i)[1] == h) {
          fallen_tetros.remove(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // ...
  // Code to lower the rows above
  // ...
}
```

`fallen_tetros` is an `ArrayList<int[]>`, and each element contains the `x` and `y` coordinates of a single square (not a full tetromino).

As you can see, I use 50x50 squares, so I check for a full line every 50 pixels, starting from the bottom (900).

What concerns me is that the row seems to be considered full since some squares get deleted. But I don't get why only half of them get deleted, and why it happens only on the highest row.

Comment: Are the squares from the row where only half of them are deleted in consecutive order in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: @MrSmith42: dude, problem solved, answer accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand exactly what's going on. Consider adding `println()` statements to your code, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fallen_tetros.size(); i++) {
   println("i: " + i);     
   if (fallen_tetros.get(i)[1] == h) {
     println("removing: " + i);
     fallen_tetros.remove(i);
     println("tetros size: " + tetros.size());
   }
}
```

But basically, your problem is caused by the fact that you're removing items from an `ArrayList` while iterating over it. When you remove an item (say, at index 0), then every other item shifts down by one. You have a new item at index 0. Then your `for` loop goes to the next index (index 1) and removes that item, and again everything is shifted down by one. You have a new item at index 1, and you move on to index 2. But notice that you're basically skipping over the item that just moved into the index you just removed!

You can get around this problem by [looping backwards](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists) or by using an `Iterator`.

Also note that it seems a little weird to mix pixel coordinates with array indexes. Just store everything in a 2D array, or an ArrayList that holds each row (instead of holding each column like your code currently works). That way you don't have to iterate over each cell individually, you can just remove the entire row all at once.

Comment: Yeah I used Processing native debugger and tried to print all my data, but couldn't understand the problem. Thanks ;)
(About the data structure, it's bad, I agree)